# Set icon from generated exe in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to **set the icon** from a generated Windows Form Application, here's my code.

```
Private Sub CompileSourceCode()

        Dim cProvider As CodeDomProvider = New VBCodeProvider
        Dim cParams As New CompilerParameters
        Dim cResult As CompilerResults
        Dim sourceCode As String = generate_exe.final_winform

        With cParams
            .GenerateInMemory = False
            .GenerateExecutable = True
            .OutputAssembly = "test.exe"
            .CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe /win32icon:eye.ico"
            .ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange({"System.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"})
            .MainClass = "MyNamespace.form1"
        End With

        cResult = cProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cParams, sourceCode)
        cProvider.Dispose()

        If cResult.Errors.HasErrors Then
            MsgBox(cResult.Errors(0).Line.ToString & ", " & cResult.Errors(0).ErrorText)
        End If

    End Sub
```

**The problem:**
 The first time i run it, it creates the EXE with the icon i chose. 
The second time, if i just change the icon i want to use but leave it as the same `OutputAssembly` name (test.exe) it creates the EXE but with the old icon, doesn't update.

**Edit:** Found a very good solution, Although It's been a long time since my question, I think it could help someone else with the same problem using `SHChangeNotify`. Add that to the top of the code:

```
Const SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED As Integer = &H8000000
    Const SHCNF_IDLIST As Integer = 0
    Private Class NativeMethods
        <DllImport("shell32")>
        Public Shared Sub SHChangeNotify(ByVal wEventId As Integer, ByVal flags As Integer, ByVal item1 As IntPtr, ByVal item2 As IntPtr)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

> **Usage:** (before or after your compile command)
>
> > `NativeMethods.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, Nothing, Nothing)`

Comment: Google "shell reset icon cache".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I found a way that works and doesn't need restart, the command `ie4uinit.exe -show` but i cant figure it out how to run it on runtime.

Comment: Having a Explorer window folder open,you want to update instantly the icon overlay of a file after that file is replaced.Well,I did a lot of tests using the `SHChangeNotify` function, first using a String signature trying to pass a string pointing to the filepath,and secondly using the original signature trying to pass a pointer using `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto` function, nothing worked for me. It seems this Win32 function is not capable to update the icon overlay of a file. It would be very nice if someone knows how to do this via Win32 API without refreshing all the icon cache.Good luck!

Comment: @ElektroStudios Thanks, I'm still searching for the answer but it seems really difficult.

Comment: @Milton Cardoso But you are aware that there is nothing wrong with your code neither with the icon file, right?, I mean your code works as expected and the icon is assigned properly, the problem is that Explorer itself doesn't refresh the icon overlay change, it is a Windows related issue. Regards.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Yes i know. Thanks for all the help! :)